# How to force an image of a ViewCell to be resized to a certain size in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is the scenario:

I have a list which can contain images of any size (400x400, 1x1, 5837x2472, you get the point). The images need to be resized so every image has the same resolution using XAML (preferably).

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

As you can see the 2nd image is too wide.

I am not very smart when it comes to images and resizing/cropping them so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

The current code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dummyTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Aspect="AspectFit"
                        Source="{Binding ImageSourceProperty}"
                        LoadingPlaceholder="placeholder_list.png"
                        ErrorPlaceholder="placeholder_list.png">
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                    <Label Text="{Binding TextProperty}" TextColor="#000000" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding DetailProperty}" TextColor="#999999" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>             
            </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am using a custom ViewCell instead of an ImageCell (even though in the end it should look like an ImageCell) because I want to use the [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) library to show placeholders.

Could anyone tell me how I could manipulate the images so they are all the same size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it with these extra attributes:

`WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300" DownsampleToViewSize="true"`, like this:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Aspect="AspectFit"
    Source="{Binding ImageSourceProperty}"
    LoadingPlaceholder="placeholder_list.png"
    ErrorPlaceholder="placeholder_list.png"
    WidthRequest="300"
    HeightRequest="300"
    DownsampleToViewSize="true">
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

This will resize the images to 300x300 and downsample them instead of zooming them which will tremendously lower your memory usage.

It is then up to you what to do with the `Aspect="AspectFit"` property. With `AspectFit` the whole image will be shown but could be letterboxed (a bar at the top and bottom) or you could go for `AspectFill` which will fill the complete 300x300 width and height, but it could be that you lose some parts of the image as they will not fit.

As pointed out in the comments; you probably want to set the `HorizontalOptions` to something different than `FillAndExpand`. Because this means that it will expand to the space that is available. Rather set it to `Start`.

Comment: Nice answer, I agree with this... I just opened the VS to test this kind of answer that I had in my head but I wanted to test it out, but seeing this code I agree with this answer this kind approach I was using last year at one of my school projects and this is a best solution. Up vote :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just tried this but nothing changed, sadly. I will work more on it tonight/tomorrow. My Product Owner told me that'd like it if the image was too big (like the 2nd one in my example) that the edges should just get "cut off" so it will be a square. Will your code example work with that?

Comment: It might be due to the HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" that the image still takes up more then you define through the Height and Width properties. You could try setting that to Start instead and define the height and width then.

Comment: Yeah for Height and WidthRequest to work you'll have to change your Horizontal and VerticalOptions from FillAndExpand, which is what it's set to by default, to Center, Start, or End